# Querying for in string array in mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have an element that looks like this:

```
{"Name":"test name","DBType":0,"UserName":"test user","Password":"","Host":"test host","Port":"123","DBName":"test schema","Options":"test options","Groups":["test1"]}
```

I want to be able to query the cataloug of Datasources for those which are assigned to a particular group.

My code for this is:

```
var d []Source
q := bson.M{"Groups": bson.M{"$in": [1]string{groupName}}}
findErr := c.Find(q).All(&d)
```

However - I get no error and no results.

I've also tried

```
q := bson.M{"Groups": groupName}
```

with the same result.

```
//Source describes a data source
type Source struct {
    Name string
    DBType      uint
    UserName    string
    Password    string
    Host        string
    Port        string
    DBName      string
    Options     string
    Groups      []string
}
```

I'm stuck - I am puzzled!  Any help appreciated.

Update - I tried

```
{"Name":"test name"}
```

and this returns 0 items.  Yet if I set to nil I get stuff.

Comment: Well you don't actually need `$in`, and it's a common misconception that you do but the "array" is of "arguments" and not "target" and MongoDB does not care if the actual data is in an array or not.  Check you actually have the correct collection and that your content in `groupName` is actually what you think it is. The only reasons for not returning anything are either you are looking in the wrong place or looking for the wrong thing. The query syntax itself is fine.

Comment: I set the query to nil and I get Sources back so the collection is correct.

Comment: Well that still leaves the input, or your interpretation thereof. So what happens when you try to match on `"Name"` or `"UserName"` or basically any other field that is not an array? Are you possibly defining `groupName` as `[]string` instead of just `string`. These are the things that will be your actual problem. There is nothing wrong with MongoDB or the driver.

Comment: `q := bson.M{"Groups": groupName}` is the correct query for your case. Have you tried your queries in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to double check the capitalisation of your document field names. For example, if in your documents you have

```
{ "Groups": ["test1", "test2"] }
```

You also need to query using capital `G` as below:

```
query := bson.M{"Groups": groupName}
```

I think the issue here is that you have lower case `groups` in your document.

Your `mgo` [Struct](https://gobyexample.com/structs) however is capital `Groups`, which `mgo` will automatically map to lower case `groups` document field. Thus querying using lower case `groups` field name will not return any match (but query all does). If this is the case, you need to query using:

```
query := bson.M{"groups": groupName}
```

If however, your document field names are in first letter capital, then you also need to specify [marshalling mapping](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal) as below:

```
type Source struct {
    Name     string   `bson:"Name"`
    DBType   uint     `bson:"DBType"`
    UserName string   `bson:"UserName"`
    Password string   `bson:"Password"`
    Host     string   `bson:"Host"`
    Port     string   `bson:"Port"`
    DBName   string   `bson:"DBName"`
    Options  string   `bson:"Options"`
    Groups   []string `bson:"Groups"`
}
```